Django RF deserialization
In django rest framework when we call post request in which we send json data to be saved in database.so how django RF handle this request and how will it receive json data how will it convert into python native and then complex data type?
What's the role of Bytes io function in this?
I just can't understand process.

"What's the role of Bytes io function in this?" I'm not sure I understand. I wouldn't normally use BytesIO to deserialize data. Can you give a specific example of how the BytesIO function might be used here?
